# loading a part of webpage asynchroneusly along with scripts?

Tags: jquery, ajax

as my title tells, i have to load a div with id 'data' and there is script tag inside it.
I can use jquery but can not use its $.load function because it strip out script tags.

i also used
 `$("#container").load("setting.php #data");`
now the javascript works well but shows whole web page. Anyone helps me please.

Note:hey i am not loading a data twice. My #container div is either blank or contain any other webpage and also at the time of loading i make sure the container is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my answer with a long search.
Code of that is
here `what`stands for url

```
    $.post(what+" #data", function(html) {
 var markup = $($.trim(html));
 markup=markup.find('#data');
 $('#working_area').html(markup);
 window.history.pushState(window.location.pathname,"",what)});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your loading your data twice here and if that is the case then u might want to recheck at  [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.The content is already loaded, and your trying again to insert it on the second line of your code. Try this:

```
$( "#container").load( "setting.php#data",function( response, status, xhr ) {
if ( status == "error" ) {
   var msg = "There was an error: ";
   $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
 }
});
```

Comment: hey i am not loading a data twice. My #container div is either blank or contain any other webpage and also @ the time of loading i blank the container.

Comment: So what is the problem your facing?

Comment: the problem was that i have some scripts in remote pages, and that was striped out now that is solved. you can check working @ http://www.funnenjoy.com or below answer